# How to variable data from one sub routine to another in vb 2012

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Label3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label3.Click

    End Sub

    Public Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles YurName.TextChanged
        Dim Name1 As String
        Name1 = YurName.Text

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Me.Close()


    End Sub

   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim total As Integer
        total = (YurName.Text.Length) + (PartName.Text.Length)
        Dim cal As Integer = 0

        MessageBox.Show("Name" & name1.length)     ------>>>>PROBLEM      


        'End While

    End Sub
End Class
```

I dont know how to call the string "name1" from "sub textbox1_textchanged" to another "sub button1_click"

plz help me guyss.

thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking for educational purposes
so, just like in access vba, whenever you need to use a variable in many subroutines, "Name1" in this case, just declare it as global variable... that would be just under

> Public Class Form1
>
> Dim Name1 as string

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `TextChanged` handler at all.  You don't need it.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim total As Integer = (YurName.Text.Length) + (PartName.Text.Length)
        Dim cal As Integer = 0
        Dim name As String = YurName.Text
        MessageBox.Show("Name" & name.length)

    End Sub
```